# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tried to run the following code but it gets this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ani123' in 'where clause'' in D:\xampp\htdocs\New folder\FINAL PROJECT\QQUIZ\admin\teacher\t_action.php:44 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\New folder\FINAL PROJECT\QQUIZ\admin\teacher\t_action.php(44): PDO->exec('DELETE FROM `qu...') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\New folder\FINAL PROJECT\QQUIZ\admin\teacher\t_action.php on line 44

Here is my code:

```
$dltQuizesSql = "DELETE FROM `quizes` WHERE `username`=".$_GET['user']; // line 44
$stmt1 = $conn->exec($dltQuizesSql);
```

And here is an image of my table:
[image]

`username` exists in my table but I still get the error.

How can I solve it?

Comment: string should be enclosed by single quotes "DELETE FROM quizes WHERE username='".$_GET['user']."'";

Comment: There is a mistake  44th line is ( $stmt1 = $conn->exec($dltQuizesSql);)

Comment: remove semicolon  inside the brackets ( $stmt1 = $conn->exec($dltQuizesSql);)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) string should be enclosed by single quotes

```
 "DELETE FROM quizes WHERE username='".$_GET['user']."'";
```

2) Remove semicolon inside the brackets

```
( $stmt1 = $conn->exec($dltQuizesSql);)
```